# Shifting around the image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i know this is an amateur question, but i have some trouble.

This is my CSS`:

```css
body{
 background-image: url(street-photography1.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 color: white;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
form{
 background-color: rgba(19, 18, 18, 0.66);
 color: white;
 padding: 40px;
 margin-top: 200px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;

}
.form-control{
 background-color: rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.35);
 border-radius: 0px;
 color: white;
}
.logo1{
 padding: 40px;
 margin-top: 200px;
 
 
}
h1{
 text-align: center;
}

.btn{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
   

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    
 <div class="container">
 <div class="column">
 <div class=" col-sm-5">
 <img class="logo1" src="images/capture.png" alt=" logo">
 </div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="row">
 
   <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-7">
   
    <form>

     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      
      <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
       <input type="checkbox"> Remember Password
     </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="col-sm-5">
      Copyright © 2016 , Singapore. All rights reserved.</p>
     
    </div>
  </footer>
  

  </body>
</html>
```

So currently my webpage looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQtTJ.jpg).

How can i shift my message logo so that the logo and my validation form are in the same line with each other?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: First of all - if you use Bootstrap you should put logo and form in one row. Pleas read more about Bootstrap grid https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can next the two col divs inside of a row. i.e.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6>...Logo...
     <div class="col-sm-6>...Form...
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `col-sm-offset-6` to the logo container if you want to align them vertically.

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-5">
<img class="logo1" src="images/capture.png" alt=" logo">
</div>
```

Or, if you want them aligned horizontally, the answer posted by @DPalmquist should do it.